# How to work around invisibility of Pane.setConstraints() method

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I'm using JavaFX to create a GUI and I've found that none of the provided layout managers meet my needs, so I'm creating my own.  I've looked at the code for some of the built-in layout managers, and a lot of them use what they call *constraints*: properties that can be applied to the children of a layout pane, which will affect how they are laid out.

In fact, this is precisely how they are implemented: the underlying `Node` class comes with an `ObservableMap` of properties, and setting constraints sets some of these properties.

The problem is that the go-between method, `Pane.setConstraints()`, is package-private to `javafx.scene.layout`, so I can't use it inside my packages.  It seems odd to me to exclude this useful piece of functionality from the API.

The best workthrough I can see at the moment is to use the `Node.setProperties()` method directly, essentially duplicating the functionality of `Pane.setConstraints()`.  Is there a different workaround that will allow me to reuse the code in the `Pane.setConstraints()` method?

`Pane.setConstraints()` is 10 lines of code, and in order to make my implementation as robust as possible, I'd essentially need to copy and paste these 10 lines into my own code in order to duplicate the functionality.

Comment: writing bug reports with use-cases and possibly "dirty" code is what the fx wants - see [Jonathan's reply](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2017-August/020700.html) on the mailing list. No guarantee not even much hope that there will be a change or if how useful it really will be (been there ... with mixed experiences ;) Until then (the current target is java10!) c&p and/or reflection is the only way out ... dirty and/or illegal ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you already have the correct solution (which is to copy and paste the code into your class).

I think the JavaFX developers want to maintain a minimum of API which is functional useful and easy to maintain from a security perspective.  Hence, sometimes there are useful functions that are "hidden" inside the JavaFX private implementations and are not readily accessible to application developers (even though the functionality might be useful).  It's a tradeoff of sorts between maintainability and functionality.

Sometimes you can work around accessibility issues using reflection to break the encapsulation.  Usually, that isn't recommended as such code may break for future Java versions because you are invoking code that is not part of the publicly supported API and lacks the backwards compatible compilation guarantees which are provided with public APIs.

You can always make a request or provide a patch request to make some functionality available (the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) is probably the best way to initiate this process).

In the past, significant functionality which was previously private in some JavaFX releases has been released in public API in subsequent releases (for example the [Skin classes for Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/253)).